# Load data from Firebase once

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Firebase as my backend service & fetching data using the `SnapshotListener` ( which keep listening for any data changes ). I want to remove that listener (only run and fetch data on first load).

```
private func loadShops(_ category: String) {
    db.collection(category).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let docs = snapshot?.documents {
            for doc in docs {
                self.shops = []
                let shopData = doc.data()
                var newShop = Shop()
                newShop.shopName = shopData["name"] as? String ?? "Empty Name"
                self.shops.append(newShop)
                self.shops.shuffle()
            }
            self.shopsView.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the API example above - I'm assuming you are using the Firestore API and not the older Firebase.

If its firestore, you could just use query fetch instead of using a snapshot listener.
Refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query

```
private func loadShops(_ category: String) {
    db.collection(category).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            for document in querySnapshot.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                // do the conversion to model object.
            }
        }
}
```

Using the snapshot listener is only if you want to continue monitoring the cloud for new documents. It is also costly as per the pricing documentation.

Comment: Thank you, that seems a prefect solution, will update my code and give you a feedback.

Comment: Could you please check this one also ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857042/fetching-images-from-firebase-storage

Comment: You should definitely try & use some solution like SDWebImage as described in the answer for that question. Since downloads are asynchronous- it involves downloading, caching & refreshing the views when download completes